# Please explain constexpr

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I have a class which contains three static constants,

```
static const int NUM_POINTS = 2000;
static const float LAKE_THRESHOLD = 0.3;
static const int NUM_LLOYD_ITERATIONS = 2;
```

In the header file. I realize that now in C++11 I have to use a constexpr but I can't figure out how to use them. Can anyone explain constexpr in a simple way?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748083/when-should-you-use-constexpr-capability-in-c11

Comment: Why do you *have* to use `constexpr`?

Answer (score 0):

constexpr can be used to mark an expression as compile-time constant.  It extends to functions as well, so an arbitrarily deep call chain can be compile-time constant.  This permits the compiler to substitute the constant value, rather than evaluating it unnecessarily at runtime.

See:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr

Comment: Ok so now I have this declared in the header:

`constexpr static float FRACTION_LAVA_FISSURES() {return 0.2;}`

Then in the .cpp I have this:

`if ((!edge.river) && (!edge.d0.water) && (!edge.d1.water)
        && (edge.d0.elevation > 0.8) && (edge.d1.elevation > 0.8)
        && (edge.d0.moisture < 0.3) && (edge.d1.moisture < 0.3)
        && ((float)(rand() / RAND_MAX) < FRACTION_LAVA_FISSURES))`

It says `invalid operands of types 'float' and 'float()' to binary 'operator<'`