# What does (&) -- ampersand in parentheses -- mean in this code?

Tags: c++, c++11

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4748339/573432), the following code is given (C++11):

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
constexpr size_t size_of(T (&)[N]) {
    return N;
}
```

What does the `(&)` mean in this context? This sort of thing is exceptionally difficult to search for.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's shorthand for something like this:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
constexpr size_t size_of(T (&anonymous_variable)[N]) {
    return N;
}
```

In the function, you don't actually need the *name* of the variable, just the template deduction on `N` - so we can simply choose to omit it. The parentheses are syntactically necessary in order to pass the array in by reference - you can't pass in an array by value.

Comment: Thanks! Does this pattern have a name?

Comment: @Phonon Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: @Phonon: It is a standard syntax that exists since the ancient C. C has no references, but array pointer types have been described as `T (*)[N]` since the beginning of times. Replacement of `*` with `&` is besides the point.

Comment: @AnT Yeah, that makes perfect sense. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Grammatically, this is an *abstract-declarator*.

Answer (score 5):

This is passing an array as a parameter by reference:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
constexpr size_t size_of(T (&)[N]) {
    return N;
}
```

As you cannot pass an array like this:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
constexpr size_t size_of(T[N]) {
    return N;
}
```

If the array was given a name, it would look like:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
constexpr size_t size_of(T (&arrayname)[N]) {
    return N;
}
```

Comment: Why is the middle block illegal?

Comment: @Phonon Arrays cannot be passed by reference; they are passed by value.