# If-Statement in C++ with empty body: is condition guaranteed to be evaluated?

Tags: c++

Given this statement (which, as a sidenote, is not my preferred coding style)

```
if( doSomething() ) {}
```

Does 'the C++ Standard' guarantee that the function is called?
(It's return value has no effect on the execution path, so the compiler
may follow the ideas of shortcut evaluation and optimize it away.)

Comment: Yes, the standard guarantees it and an optimizer isn't allowed to change the semantic effect.

Comment: You can just write `(void) doSomething();` if you want to explicitly discard the return value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no short-circuit operator involved, so the function is guaranteed to be called if it can't be optimized away without removing side-effects. Quoting the C++11 standard:

> [...] conforming
>   implementations are required to emulate (only) the observable behavior of the abstract machine as explained
>   below.<sup>5</sup>
>
> <sup>5</sup>  This provision is sometimes called the “as-if” rule [...] an actual implementation need not evaluate part of an expression
>   if it can deduce that its value is not used and that no side effects
>   affecting the observable behavior of the program are produced.

So, something like

```
int doSomething() { return 1; }
```

might be optimized away, but

```
int doSomething() { std::cout << "d\n"; return 1; }
```

isn't allowed to.

Additionally, since C++11, you can write more sophisticated functions and still make them evaluated at compile time by using [`constexpr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748083/when-should-you-use-constexpr-capability-in-c11).