# Writing a C macro to use inside a CUDA kernel

Tags: c, cuda, macros

I have the following structure inside a code and it has been used many times. So, improving the code readability and decreasing the number of lines, I really need to use a macro instead of that. The part which I am looking to write a macro for it is as follow:

```
#define _UNROLL_FACTOR_volIntGrad 32
    int jj = 0;
    for (; jj < (ngbSize - 32); jj += 32) {
        int j = offset + jj;
#pragma unroll
        for (int k = 0; k < 32; k++){
        ...
        arbitrary calculation 1 (depends on k)
        ...
        }
        ...
        arbitrary calculation 2
        ...
    }

    for (; jj < (ngbSize - (_UNROLL_FACTOR_volIntGrad / 2)); jj+= (_UNROLL_FACTOR_volIntGrad / 2)){
        int j = offset + jj;
#pragma unroll
        for (int k = 0; k < 16; k++){
        ...
        arbitrary calculation 1 (depends on k)
        ...
        }
        ...
        arbitrary calculation 2
        ...
    }

    for (; jj < (ngbSize - (_UNROLL_FACTOR_volIntGrad / 4)); jj+= (_UNROLL_FACTOR_volIntGrad / 4)){
        int j = offset + jj;
 #pragma unroll
        for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++){
        ...
        arbitrary calculation 1 (depends on k)
        ...
        }
        ...
        arbitrary calculation 2
        ...
    }

    for (; jj < (ngbSize - (_UNROLL_FACTOR_volIntGrad / 8)); jj+= (_UNROLL_FACTOR_volIntGrad / 8)){
        int j = offset + jj;

 #pragma unroll
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++){
        ...
        arbitrary calculation 1 (depends on k)
        ...
        }
        ...
        arbitrary calculation 2
        ...
    }

    for (; jj < (ngbSize - (_UNROLL_FACTOR_volIntGrad / 16)); jj+= (_UNROLL_FACTOR_volIntGrad / 16)){
        int j = offset + jj;
#pragma unroll
        for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++){
        ...
        arbitrary calculation 1 (depends on k)
        ...
        }
        ...
        arbitrary calculation 2
        ...
    }
    for (; jj < ngbSize; jj++){
        int j = offset + jj;
        ...
        arbitrary calculation 3
        ...
    }
}
```

by arbitrary calculation X, I mean a set of calculations which is independent of macro and differs function by function. Does anyone know how to write this macro in order to decrease the above structure's size? for example like the following:

```
__MACRO
     arbitrary calculation 1 
     arbitrary calculation 2
     arbitrary calculation 3
__END
```

Comment: Consider to write a function before a macro

Comment: I presume you've done a fair bit of testing to establish that manually unrolling (and the corresponding increase in complexity and decrease in legibility) causes a statistically significant and worthwhile performance benefit?

Comment: @EOF Yes exactly right! This part of a GPU kernel and really need to make the loop size know for compiler to make it possible to unroll in order to improve the performance. But legibility decreases :-(.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem5. Never use a macro you can use other measures. Problem is, you tagged for two **different** languages, C and C++. Both provide different alternatives. Pick the language you actually use and you might get a better alternative. (You have to clar4ify your question, too, though).

Comment: @Siamak So is this actually opencl or cuda or compute-shaders or anything like that? Otherwise, modern C-compilers will generally unroll automatically where applicable, and your manual unrolling can interfere with that.

Comment: @EOF Actually it is CUDA. The problem is not manually unroll. I have unknown `ngbSize`, so I break it to smaller parts with known loop size and make compiler able to unroll it (at least the smaller part). Please look at the code and you will realize the process.

Comment: @Siamak: I don't think your current approach of multiple differently unrolled loops is reasonable. I'd try to padd the blocks to a common size and unroll for that size only.

Comment: @EOF As the `ngbSize`is not known (lets assume somthing between 30 and 50), I need to start with a big value such as `32` and decrease it step by step to decrease the non-unrolled part size as much as possible.

Comment: @Siamak: Or you padd it to a multiple of 32. You only need one unrolled loop, which is simple enough to write that you don't need a macro. It's probably considerably faster too.

Comment: Lets say `ngbSize` is 32. `jj` is 0 and the code starts with `for (; jj < (ngbSize - 32); jj += 32)`. Is `0 < (ngbSize - 32)`?

Comment: @kfsone In this case, it doe not go inside the loop.and jumps to next loop with 'ngbSize = 16' .

Answer (score 2):

In C++, it is mostly frowned upon to use macros for anything other than include guards and conditional compilation for platform dependencies. The best thing to do would be to create a static constant that will be internally linked and has a single point of maintenance. You can put this at the top of your file.

If you're using C++11, then you can use a `constexpr` for what you are trying to do. The compiler will know your statement has a type rather than just a text replacement, which is essentially what C-style macros do.

The purpose of a `constexpr` is to create an immutable object that can be computed at compile time, sort of like a static constant. But the great thing about them is that you can create static functions with them, so that would be useful in your case where you are doing calculations that are dependent on others.

See the usage for `constexpr` here: 
[When should you use constexpr capability in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748083/when-should-you-use-constexpr-capability-in-c11)

Comment: You might want to explain how `constexpr` is supposed to help with the OP's particular problem, otherwise this doesn't look like it answers the question.

Comment: @JessicaAboukasm Unfortunately the OP has changed his mind, this is a C (in fact, CUDA) question :(

Comment: @kfsone the CUDA `nvcc`compiler follows C++ rules, and claims C++ compliance.