# Should I make reference for a lambda?

Tags: c++, lambda, reference, value-categories

Should I make reference for a lambda to avoid copying it?

Will this code make a copy of the lambda:

```
auto myLambda = []() {/* do stuff */ }
```

and if yes, should I write it like this:

```
auto &myLambda = []() {/* do stuff */ }
```

P.S. Please sorry for a possibly newbie question, googled, but didn't find answer.

Comment: The second snippet doesn't compile, which might already give you a hint here.

Comment: @lubgr Really? What's your compiler, is it GCC? I used msvc and c++17 flags and it compiles.

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev you forgot the `const`? In any case, just use `auto myLambda = []() {}`.

Comment: not very different from `int i = 5;` no copy here

Comment: MSVS is known for allowing references to bind to rvalues, which is illegal in C++. `const auto&`, however, should work. Regardless, the first snippet does not copy anything. Copy-elision kicks in. What's more, if that lambda is stateless, it's size is 1 byte, which, in comparison to reference's (usually) 4 or 8 bytes, makes the first approach faster and preferable.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 but that's a literal. And I doubt lambdas considered as literals by compilers, hence the question..

Comment: What do you think a literal is and how does it differ in terms of generated assembly? Have you looked at the generated assembly of both approaches?

Comment: then consider `Foo f = Foo();` still no copy

Comment: @Fureeish So lambdas are literals to compilers? I just don't know, I thought maybe it still lives somewhere in memory, so we should make reference. But now I think I was wrong

Comment: Why should it be a literal? It's a lambda.

Comment: No, they are not, but for some reason you assume some facts about literals.

Comment: Have a look at @formerlyknownas_463035818's second example (`Foo f = Foo();`) again; provide that foo class with custom default constructor and assignment operator. You'll notice that only the constructor will get called, f is constructed right in place. Same for the lambda.

Comment: @Fureeish Just to finish the conversation... I mentioned literals because I've read that literals must not and can not be refererenced, because they don't occupy any space in memory. So I wondered if the same applies to lambdas or not. BTW thanks for the answer! (I've chosen the other one because it was made a bit earlier). Also, now I know, thanks to all you guys and especially L.F. that that's (literals, lambdas, non-reference function call results etc) called prvalue :)

Comment: "*I've read that literals must not and can not be refererenced*" - well, `const int& ref = 5;` should and will compile.

Comment: @Fureeish Yep, I've read about that as well, but that's a constant and it's just a better alternative for `#define`. That's just what I've read, can't remember where exactly though... Anyway the question is solved, thanks!

Comment: _"that's a constant and it's just a better alternative for `#define`"_ - no, [it's way more than that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42388077/constexpr-vs-macros) (note: referring to `constexpr` rather than `const`here, but the difference is explained in the answer as well).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the first one because the second one is ill-formed according to the C++ standard.

[[expr.prim.lambda]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#2):

> **A *lambda-expression* is a prvalue** whose result object is called the closure object. [ *Note:* A closure object behaves like a function
>   object. — *end note*  ]

You cannot bind prvalues to lvalue references per [[dcl.init.ref]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#5).  The fact that a particular compiler appears to accept it doesn't change anything.  C++ is defined by the C++ standard.

In fact, the first one is guaranteed not to introduce a copy since C++17 — initializing from prvalues is guaranteed to construct the value in place.  In practice, every decent compiler does the copy elision optimization, so you can safely assume that no copy is made.

Comment: Hmm interesting, you made me read about what is prvalue (Yes, I am just learning c++), so prvalue is pure value, like a value that cannot change, and that includes lambdas. Thanks!

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev Yes!  If you change the "literals" in your comments to "prvalues", they make sense :)

Answer (score 3):

> Will this code make a copy of the lambda:
>
> ```
> auto myLambda = []() {/* do stuff */ }
> ```

No. Copy-initialisation kicks in and, regardless of the *copy* in the name, only one object is created.

> and if yes, should I write it like this:
>
> ```
> auto &myLambda = []() {/* do stuff */ }
> ```

Even if that was a copy, the above code is illegal in C++. Lvalue references cannot bind to rvalues (and a lambda expression is a prvalue, as per `[expr.prim.lambda]/2:`). MSVS introduces an extension which allows that - whether we like it or not. `const auto&` would make it work, but that would almost certainly be a pessimisation.