# In C++, why would you use `uint8_t` to declare a string?

Tags: c++, uint8t

As a mobile developer working with React Native, I need to work with a C++ code that creates and encrypts files. I don't have much experience with C++ (the last time I wrote some was over 15 years ago at university).

**Please correct me if I'm wrong.**

This bugs me so much. Here is the type definition of the file:

```cpp
typedef struct File 
{
    uint8_t FileName[64];
    uint8_t userName[64];
}File;
```

Why would you use the type `uint8_t` to store string instead of `std::string`?

Later on, it becomes even more confusing. We need to parse all the characters one by one and write them to a temporary file.

```cpp
#define FILE_NAME_LEN   64


CustomFile CFile::getCustomFileFromFile(tFile f_File)
{
    CustomFile returnValue;
    for(int i = 0;i<FILE_NAME_LEN;i++){
        returnValue.FileName[i] = f_File.FileName[i]; 
    }
    for(int i = 0;i<FILE_NAME_LEN;i++){
        returnValue.user_name[i] = f_File.user_name[i];
    }
    return returnValue;
}



bool WriteEncryptFile(QString fpath,tFile *p_tFile)
{
    // Convert the tFile object to a CustomFile object
    CustomFile customFile = CFile::getCustomFileFromFile(*p_tFile);
}
```

Comment: It bugs me too.  Who wrote that definition?

Comment: `typedef struct File { ... } File;` shows that this was written by a C programmer, which might explain the use of C-style arrays.

Comment: I could see someone doing this if they are getting binary data and copying it into an object.  That is not easy to do with a `std::string` but `uint8_t` gives you a fixed known size

Comment: Terminology side note: "a C++ script" - C++ is *not* a scripting language, it's a compiled language and C++ source files are *not* scripts.

Comment: (1) that's a `C` (compatible) structure definition (note the `typedef`), and (2) possibly as a hint that the filenames are UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: You might do this if you needed to guarantee that no implicit memory-allocations/deallocations would occur during the execution of the code (e.g. because the code needs to run reliably in a real-time context).  Of course you probably would not be reading/writing a file from that context, but if you e.g. needed to pass the struct to a real-time thread you might want to ensure that even if the real-time thread copies the struct, it doesn't cause any heap allocations to occur there.

Comment: "`#define  FILE_NAME_LEN 
 64`" - Why use a macro for a constant when you can use a proper `const` or `constexpr` *variable*? (Like `constexpr int FILE_NAME_LEN = 64;`).

Comment: @JesperJuhl It's one of those "C+" code samples.

Comment: The use of `uint8_t`, a.k.a. `unsigned char` as opposed to simple `char` may be due to concerns that `char` can be signed or unsigned depending on the platform. Normally that's not a concern but I can see people being cautious about that, maybe if they want to do direct bit manipulation to check whether bytes are 7 bit ASCII or convert between lower- and upper-case

Comment: Still one can use `std::u8string` or if that is not available in that c++ version, `std::basic_string<unsigned char>` instead of raw arrays.

Comment: If fixed-length 64B strings were the intention, then in C++ (not C) this would be `struct File { std::array<uint8_t, 64> FileName; std::array<uint8_t, 64> UserName; };` However, the fixed number `64` is way too arbitrary for any reasonable purpose.

Comment: @Homer512 Sure, whether or not `char` is signed or unsigned is not often something people worry about, but since I was first bitten by that on AiX with the Xlc++ compiler I've always been very aware of it  (it exposed bugs in my code that didn't show up on Solaris or x86 Linux)

Comment: But do you have a question, or are you just asking to have your opinion of someone else's code affirmed?  In my experience other peoples code always sucks, not all code can be written by people with expertise and experience.  Perhaps this code has been written by someone either experienced in C or is simply a direct port of existing C code. The whole `typedef struct File` thing is certainly a C idiom unnecessary in C++.  Moreover it looks like Qt code, so perhaps `QString` rather the `std::string` would be better.  It is also odd to use `uint8_t` rather than `char`.

Comment: It can also be a legacy code and no one is bold enough to update this.

Comment: Maybe the data was not of type `string` when the original author wrote the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why would you use the type `uint8_t` to store string instead of `std::string`

Because whoever decided to do so is a C developer with little expertise in idiomatic C++. This can also be seen in habits like:

- using `uint8_t` instead of `std::uint8_t` despite potential compatibility issues
- using raw arrays instead of `std::array`

  - [What are the advantages of using std::array over C-style arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30263303/5740428)
- using `typedef struct File` even though `typedef` is unnecessary here

  - to be fair, if this is in a C/C++ compatibility header, the last bullets are perfectly justified
- using macros instead of `constexpr` constants (assuming that isn't your code)

  - [When should I prefer constexpr variables over macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42388077/5740428)

That being said, there are practical reasons too.
`std::string` performs dynamic allocations, and this may not be desirable, especially in an embedded environment.
Still, it would probably make more sense to use `char FileName[64];` instead.

The use of `uint8_t` likely comes from a desire to make the code "more portable", since `char` is not guaranteed to be 8 bits large (it can be wider). It probably is on any machine you will ever compile your code on, but still, some people are annoyed by this technicality and use `uint8_t`. See also [When is uint8_t ≠ unsigned char?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16138237/5740428)

It may also be motivated by the varying signedness of `char`, though `signed char` or `unsigned char` solve that. See also [Is char signed or unsigned by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2054939/5740428)

If you have the freedom to modify the original code, and dynamic allocations are acceptable, you can simply write:

```cpp
struct File {
    std::string FileName;
    std::string userName;
};
```

If you need all string data to be in the `struct`, you can use `std::array<char, 64>` instead.
This still simplifies the subsequent code because you can write:

```cpp
// std::array has an assignment operator
returnValue.FileName = f_File.FileName;
```

Comment: Except it's fake portability, `uint8_t` is optional. On platforms where `char` is not 8 bits, it's likely to not exist.

Comment: The possibility of `char` being signed or unsigned on different platforms is not the only concern. `char`, `signed char` & `unsigned char` are actually 3 different *types* and in some contexts that's important, even if one has the same signedness as another.

Comment: "you can use std::array<char, 64> instead"  Not if you care about the in-memory layout.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103244/is-the-size-of-stdarray-defined-by-standard.  The correct declaration is likely to be `char8_t FileName[64];`

Comment: Re: "`char` is not guaranteed to be 8 bits large" -- `char` is required to be at least 8 bits. If it's larger, `uint8_t` won't exist.

Comment: @BenVoigt I think `std::array`'s layout falls into the category of *"no sane compiler would ever do this differently"*, as so many things in C++. If you're still worried, you can add `static_assert(sizeof(std::array<char, 64>) == 64)`. I bet you ten bucks that this assertion never fails :)

Comment: _"a desire to make the code "more portable", since char is not guaranteed to be 8 bits large."_  - but C strings are of type `char` regardless.  So if you want compatibility with string literals and `<cstring>`, `char` would be more portable.  Platforms I have used where `char` is not 8 bits (TI C2000) also do not have `uint8_t`, so portability is not served at all by this.

Comment: Lack of `std::array` and `constexpr` can also be explained with code being so old, that those things simply didn't exist in C++ at the time.