# Using macro definition vs const variable

Tags: c++, variables, constants, preprocessor

I have few questions about pre-processor macros. Here is an example of 2 different code pieces to talk about;

```
tmp.h
#define DEFAULT_STRING "default_value"

tmp.cpp
void tmpFunc(std::string newValue){
    m_stringValue = newValue;
    if(newValue.isEmpty())
        newValue = DEFAULT_STRING; 
}
```

And the second version

```
tmp.h
const std::string m_defaultValue = "default_value"

tmp.cpp
void tmpFunc(std::string newValue){
    m_stringValue = newValue;
    if(newValue.isEmpty())
        newValue = m_defaultValue; 
}
```

So my questions are;

- Does the first version increase the binary size (comparing the first second)?
- Does the second version consume more memory (comparing the first one)?
- What are the performance impacts of both implementations? Which should run faster and why?
- Which is preferable/beneficial in which condition?
- Is there any better way for implementation of setting the default value?

Thanks.

Comment: There are already so many posts about this topic ... one of them is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637332/static-const-vs-define

Comment: No, it's not an exact duplicate. The other question does not ask these specific questions about the two approaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the first version increase the binary size (comparing the first second)?

No. Since the string is used only once, it will appear only once in the compiled file.

> Does the second version consume more memory (comparing the first one)?

No. It works with memory in pretty much the same manner.

> What are the performance impacts of both implementations? Which should run faster and why?

Both implementations copy the string around: the method receives `newValue` by value, copying it. This copying will dominate the performance, I guess.

However, as always with performance, just measure it - it should be easy, since you already have both versions of the code implemented.

> Which is preferable/beneficial in which condition?

Macros are not an idiomatic solution in C++. Use the `const` string.

> Is there any better way for implementation of setting the default value?

Receive the new string by reference. Other than that, not so much. I assume here the default is a short string, like `"none"` or `"default"`. These strings have [short string optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10319672/509868), so it doesn't matter much how you store it.

As always with performance, **if** you see that your method is a performance bottleneck, optimize it. If you don't know, don't optimize it.

Comment: I use references very often but is there any significant difference to pass the primitive types by reference?

Answer (score 2):

Both are horrible, the second one marginally better than the first.

The best way is to use

```
constexpr char DEFAULT_STRING[] = "default_value";
```

For more on `constexpr`, see [When should you use constexpr capability in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748083/when-should-you-use-constexpr-capability-in-c11)

Comment: could you please elaborate more on why it is better?

Comment: Why not a `constexpr std::string` then?

Comment: @YSC, your compiler will puke on that. `string_view` was added in C++17 to help.

Comment: @YSC because `std::basic_string` does not have constexpr constructors. In idea the `constexpr std::string_view foo("abc");` should work but ... does not on majority of compilers yet. So char array is fine at the moment.

Comment: True. Maybe a [`std::string_view`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95358d7f60a7c24d) then. At that point, I'm starting to agree with you with the use of `char[]`.