# Are there benefits to using a constexpr variable that is never intended to be used in a constant expression?

Tags: c++, constexpr

This is a follow up question to [this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748083/when-should-you-use-constexpr-capability-in-c11)

From one of the answers in the question linked, it makes sense that the purpose of declaring a variable as `constexpr` is not truly to inform the compiler of the possibility of using that variable as a constant expression (although this *is* the end behavior of the compiler) but rather to convey to other programmers the **intent** that the variable can be used in a constant expression. My question is whether there is any benefit, performance or otherwise, to declaring a variable as `constexpr` if the variable is **not** intended to be used in a constant expression (e.g. a constant member variable of a class which only appears in non-constant expressions with other non-const member variables). Also assume that this is not for an embedded system.

I work with code where the previous developers seem to use `constexpr` like it's candy even when it's not clear that the intent is for the variable to be used in a constant expression (like in the example from the previous paragraph). I want to know if they knew something that I don't.

Comment: Well, it indicates as a non changable constant and the compiler will complain if you try, much like `const` does. Plain usage of `const` doesn't guarantee evaluation at compile time though.

Comment: I call it future proofing.  You might not intend to use it at compile time now, but who knows what you'll need 10 years from know.  If it can be a `constexpr`, might as well make it one.

Comment: Is future proofing the only benefit? On all other metrics, are `const` and `constexpr` considered the same?

Comment: @AdamSperry AFAIK; no, `const` is declared at compile and it prevents the changing of runtime evaluation. `constexpr` is declared and evaluated both at compile time. In the sense that the values of a named variable or function can not be modified then yes they are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

> but rather to convey to other programmers the intent that the variable can be used in a constant expression.

This is a matter of opinion but I beg to differ.

In principle, I think it is better to make everything that can be known and computed at compile time a `constexpr`. The fact that it can also be used in constant expressions is a side benefit. Use of `constexpr` may have performance related benefits too.

The key point I want to make is that "the value is known at compile time" is a characteristic of the variable/data. It is better to capture that characteristic by using a language provided feature. The only time one could justify not using it will be if there are any adverse side effects.

Comment: I see your point, but what about cases like in the answer by Filip Roséen - refp to the question I linked? The function `f()` certainly could have been a `constexper` before the optimization, but afterward it cannot. This would break any code that uses `f()` in a `constexper`. I understand that there is some opinion to whether `constexper` should be used. My question is whether there are other benefits besides the ones already discussed. You mention performance benefits. Are these for sure or are you just postulating?

Comment: @AdamSperry, I am speculating about performance. Coincidentally, both of us express the same idea. What I call *the characteristic of the variable/data* he calls *intent*.

Comment: @R Sahu, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `constexpr` variables are useful for more than just conveying intent and using in other constant expressions.

If you mark a variable `constexpr`, the compiler will enforce that it itself is initialized with a constant expression.  You can use this to make sure that the things you expect to be evaluated at compile time actually are.  For example:

```
constexpr int constexpr_function() { return 123; }
int expensive_runtime_function() { return 123; }

void f()
{
    constexpr int good1 = constexpr_function(); // OK.
    // constexpr int good2 = expensive_runtime_function(); // Good: error.

    const int bad1 = constexpr_function(); // OK.
    const int bad2 = expensive_runtime_function(); // Bad: unexpected runtime cost.
}
```

Comment: So if I understand, you are saying that the difference between `constexpr int a = 1*2*5;` and `const int a = 1*2*5;` is that the value of `a` will be evaluated at compile time rather than run-time for the `constexpr` version? This seems to be a small benefit to me, but nonetheless answers the question

Comment: bad1 could still result in a runtime cost depending on your compiler

Comment: @AdamSperry In that case, I believe `a` is a constant expression whether or not it's marked `constexpr`.  (Note that even before we had `constexpr`, we could do things like `const int a=1; t<a>();`.)  What's more important, in my opinion, is that if it ever *stops* being evaluable at compile time, the compiler will complain.  Imagine if it were `const int a = x*5+y*z`, where those variables are their own non-trivial expressions.

Comment: @JVApen Correct.  Unfortunately, even `good1` could have a runtime cost.  The standard only notes that "constant expressions may be evaluated during translation" - not that they *must* be.

Comment: @Maxpm: If I remember well, if the variable is constexpr it should evaluate it at compile time