# constexpr functions clarification

Tags: c++, constexpr

I've looked up multiple questions related to this but haven't found a satisfying answer.
So:

- What does constexpr do, when applied to a function?
- Why should we use constexpr on functions? What's a big difference between using it and not using it?
- Could you provide some examples regarding constexpr functions?

I am asking this because I noticed that for example, std::array provides constexpr member functions to overload operator []. What's the reason behind having overloaded operator [] as constexpr?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What specifically don't you understand from this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr (which fully defines what constexpr functions are and do, with examples)

Comment: I do understand part of the reference, but what I don't specifically get is why and when should we use constexpr. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should you use constexpr capability in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748083/when-should-you-use-constexpr-capability-in-c11)