# Macro can be converted to constexpr

Tags: c++, visual-c++, constexpr, code-analysis

I have seen a similar discussion here ([When should you use constexpr capability in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4748083/2287576)).

```
#define kMaxLength 50
#define kSlipsModeSelect 0
#define kSlipsModeAll 1
#define kStatusBarIconWidth 20
```

All of the above are flagging code analysis:

> Macro can be converted to `constexpr`

It is proposing:

```
constexpr auto kMaxLength = 50;
constexpr auto kSlipsModeSelect = 0;
constexpr auto kSlipsModeAll = 1;
constexpr auto kStatusBarIconWidth = 20;
```

What are the benefits of making this change?