# In C++11 or later is there a way to have a constexpr that determines endian without UB?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Note that earlier similar questions I found were before C++11 and/or included UB and/or could not be a constexpr.

Not a dup of
[Is there a way to do a C++ style compile-time assertion to determine machine's endianness?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280162/is-there-a-way-to-do-a-c-style-compile-time-assertion-to-determine-machines-e) or similar

AFAIK there is `little endian`, `big endian`, and `other`.  At a minimum I need to at least not compile if `other`, even better if `other` architectures can be added

[constexpr and endianness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583791/constexpr-and-endianness) was asked earlier and does not include `other`, which would leave `other` architectures ill defined as one or the other

Basically I want to be able to specialize a `template` based on the target architecture's endianness

Comment: By 'other' do you mean  something exotic like middle-endian or mixed-endian or runtime switchable architectures?

Comment: as commented below, `__ORDER_PDP_ENDIAN__` would qualify

Comment: There are architectures where there is no compile time answer to the question since it is a runtime setting. Apparently some PowerPC processors can even select on a per-page basis.

Comment: @mattnewport:  A C++ compiler typically targets a hardware/OS combination.  Are you aware of such a combination where the endian can vary at C++ application run time?

Comment: @HowardHinnant I'm only going by Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Bi-endian_hardware - I haven't actually encountered such a system myself in the wild. It sounds like they exist though, perhaps in embedded systems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As part of my [hash_append work](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3980.html) I hope to provide what you're asking for:

https://github.com/HowardHinnant/hash_append/blob/master/endian.h

`other` would be detected by:

```
endian::native != endian::little && endian::native != endian::big
```

The first `static_assert` in this header is currently incorrect with respect to the `other` issue and should be removed.

This header is very easy to provide for any given platform.  But of course it is not portable, and thus is ideal to have it be provided by your std::lib implementor instead.

Comment: I was hoping for something that works on all compliant compilers on all architectures. BTW, for GNU there seems to also be `__ORDER_PDP_ENDIAN__`

Comment: Yeah, me too.  Bar bet:  Name a machine for which `__BYTE_ORDER__ == __ORDER_PDP_ENDIAN__`, and there exists a compiler which defines `__cplusplus >= 201103`. :-)

Comment: We don't make bar bets on SO, we make posts :) :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32218129/what-exactly-is-order-pdp-endian

Comment: Well done! :-)  You neglected the second part of that bet ... er post: `__cplusplus >= 201103`.

Comment: First things first. I was hoping that might be in somebodt's answer. But, given the lack of activity, I doubt I'll get to part two.  At least now `__ORDER_PDP_ENDIAN__` is searchable on SO