# Is bitmask necessary when assigning a value from a big type to a small one?

Tags: c++

Lets say I want to store the low 16 bits of a uint32_t in a uint16_t on windows, I could do it either

```
uint32_t value = 123456789;
uint16_t low1 = value; //like this
uint16_t low2 = value & 0xFFFF; //or this
```

There appears to be no difference in the results but I couldn't find any documentation explicitly stating that this is defined behavior. Could it be different under circumstances X or Y? Or is this just how it works?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens when I assign long int to int in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652556/what-happens-when-i-assign-long-int-to-int-in-c)

Comment: the high bits are always truncated, no need to mask

Comment: [When an int is cast to a short and truncated, how is the new value determined](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34885966/995714)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: The question you link to concerns signed integers. This question is about unsigned integers. The rules are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++ standard guarantees that assignment to and initialization of unsigned types gives you the value modulo 2<sup>*n*</sup>, where *n* is the number of bits in the value representation of the unsigned type.

In Windows all bits participate in the value representation.

Hence using a bitmask serves no purpose other than to put a little stumbling block in the way for the future, when one might change the types.

---

If you absolutely want to use a mask, e.g. to avoid a compilation warning from an over-zealous compiler, then you can do it in a type-independent way like this, assuming that the type is unsigned:

```
uint16_t low2 = value & uint16_t(-1);
```

Which relies on the aforementioned modulo-2<sup>*n*</sup> guarantee.

Comment: Isn't it better to use `~0` for the mask? `-1` is not a valid value for an unsigned int and might not produce the correct bit mask for all systems (e.g. embedded systems without two complement).

Comment: @Rocki: The code is valid, *for the reasons stated*. And contrary to your impression (where on Earth did you get it) it always produces the correct mask, since it is of the correct type. `~0`, on the other hand, is of incorrect type `int`.

Comment: @Alf I meant `uint16_t low2 = value & uint16_t(~0);`. Today almost all computers use two's complement and your assumption that -1 produce the correct bit mask is correct, but imagine a architecture with ones' complement where `uint16_t(-1)` leads to the bit mask `1111 1111 1111 1110`.

Comment: @Rocki: There is no dependency on architecture: the result is guaranteed by the C++ standard. As stated in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler should give you a warning, that `value` will be truncated if you use `-Wconversion`.

```
warning: conversion to 'uint16_t {aka short unsigned int}' from 'uint32_t {aka unsigned int}' may alter its value [-Wconversion]
uint16_t low1 = value;
                  ^
```

With bitmask g++ do not produce a warning...

Comment: while true, this doesn't answer the question *is a bit mask necessary?*