# C++ bitwise operation reverse

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I got the following operation:

```
uint8_t input = 10;
uint8_t output = ((0x190 - (input * 8)) & 0xFF);

// newInput should be 10 again, but is 255
uint8_t newInput = (((output * 8) + 0x190) | 0xFF);
```

How can I correct the operation setting `newInput` so that it will result back in 10?

Comment: `if value ==184 value = 25;`?

Comment: `| (0 & 0x07)` does nothing! tried it and got 200 for 25. and what's the type of `my_value` ?

Comment: my_value is typeof uint8_t

Comment: @Alex parenthesis are not even balanced, did you copy it correctly?

Comment: Multiplication by even numbers (so also 8) is not invertable

Comment: Wait, you are ORing a byte wide number with 0xFF and getting surprised that the result is 0xFF?  AND and OR are different, but  not the 'reverse' of each other

Comment: But put a NOT operation in there, then then you get a reverse  like in ` | ~0xff`  But that's just ORing with zero, and doing nothing.  (odd, code markup is not working here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to invert the transformation that got you `output` from `input` but unfortunately the logic is flawed. `|` is not an inverse of `&` and `* 8` is absolutely not inverse to another `* 8`. Also, if you want to reverse the action of `y = 0x190 - x`, it's not a `+` but rather another `x = 0x190 - y` (try it on paper!) Finally, if you had all the operations all right, the order of the operations would need to be reversed in order to undo them (first in, last out).

In fact, your transformation can not be inverted, because it loses part of the information that defines `input`. (Mathematically speaking, it is not injective.) Consider:

```
uint8_t input = 10;
uint8_t output = ((0x190 - (input * 8)) & 0xFF); /* 0x40 */

uint8_t input2 = 42;
uint8_t output2 = ((0x190 - (input2 * 8)) & 0xFF); /* also 0x40! */
```

If you had a function that would undo the operation, what would it be expected to return for an `output` of `0x40`, 10 or 42? This has no solution. If you want the original `input` you'll need to keep a copy of that variable somewhere.

Examples of operations that can be undone in unsigned 8-bit calculations are

- addition and subtraction OF a constant: `y = x + a` ⇔ `x = y - a`,
- subtraction FROM a constant: `y = c - x` ⇔ `x = c - y`, including plain negation (`c` = 0),
- XOR: `y = x ^ p` ⇔ `x = y ^ p`, including `~x` (that's `x ^ 0xFF`),
- multiplication by a constant in *some* cases (by odd numbers), but the inverse is not obvious.

An inverse operation to a compound like `y = -((x + 0x17) ^ 0x15)` would look like `x = ((-y) ^ 0x15) - 0x17`, notice the reverse order in which the steps are undone.

On the other hand, these are not invertible:

- AND,
- OR,
- multiplication by an even number,
- bit shifts,
- etc.

Sometimes you can find *an* inverse if that's workable for you. Here, if you are guaranteed that `input` is between `0` and `18` (that is `0x90 / 8`), you can try

```
uint8_t input = 10;
uint8_t output = 0x90 - (input * 8); // spot two differences
uint8_t newInput = (0x90 - output) / 8;
```

But if `input` is larger, for example 20, it will instead give some other value that happens to produce the same `output`.

Comment: Also, even assuming you had a sequence of injective operations, you would in general need to apply the reverse operations in the reverse order to get back to the original value

Comment: e.g. ( ( ( output | ( magic & 0xFF00 ) ) + 0x190 ) / 8 ), for some value of magic

Comment: @Caleth I added such sentence at some point in the first paragraph but maybe you were displayed the previous edit.

Comment: Indeed you did! Do you agree with my example nearly-inverse?

Comment: @Caleth Not really, `0x190 - x` is self-inverse. So even the honest attempt at the `+` was a mistake actually :-) I should also mention that.

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems why your code won't work, let me explain some of them:

1. You have an unsigned 8 bit integer, so you can use values between 0x00 and 0xFF. `0x190 - (10 *8) = 0x190 - 0x50 = 0x140` can be done but afterwards you cut of the leading 1 with the &FF, so you lose information that can't be restored afterwards.
2. The `| FF` is a bitwise OR, which turns every bit of your calculation to 1, so you will always get `0xFF = 255` , regardless of your output.
3. Your calculation is wrong.
4. It is dangerous to use decimal numbers (10) and hexadecimal numbers (0x190) in one calculation. It can be confusing.

I recommend to ensure that you won't overflow you variables. Use other constants so you will stay in the range of unit8_t or use another Type like int16_t which wont overflow with those little numbers.
Be aware of your bitwise operators. Like I said the last OR will always make newInput=255.

Here is an example which will work for the given parameters:

```
int16_t input = 10; // int16_t wont overflow
int16_t output = ((0x190 - (input * 8)) ); // without &FF there is no
                                            // loss of information

int16_t newInput = (0x190- output) / 8; // Reshape of the line obove
```

Answer (score 1):

Several points here:

1. You appear to be trying to use `& 0xFF` to truncate to 8-bits, you should get rid of that since the standard already guarantees this will happen for unsigned integers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36234166/2642059
2. You should be doing `(0x190 - output) / 8U` to recover input, so even if the sizes permitted your math is wrong:

*o = 400 - 8x*
*o - 400 = -8x*
*(o - 400) / -8 = x*

3. 400 in binary is `0b1'1001'0000` so since the downcast is truncating the most significant bit it may and may not be set, thus you will always have 2 potential answers (where `output` is positive):

```
const uint8_t newInputSmall = (0x190 - (output | 0b1'0000'0000)) / 8U;
cosnt uint8_t newInputLarge = (0x190 - output) / 8U;
```

4. You'll need to handle the possibility that `output` is negative because `input * 8U` is larger than 400